# which o.s. supports file custom extended attributes?

Tags: operating-system

I want to develop a cross-platform utility that works with custom or extended file attributes.

Do you know which commonly used Operating Systems support this feature ?
Need that info:

- Windows which versions ?
- Mac OS, classic Mac or Mac OS X ?
- Linux "Distros" ?
- BSD ?
- Other (Solaris, Unix, other)

Any links ? Thanks.

Comment: Please read this article, [Extended_file_attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I think depends your file system. customized extended attributes depend File System, so then I don't think you can get a cross-platform solution. NTFS on Windows, Ext on Linux they are totally different...